# What soul stealing monsters exist in the 5th edition official material?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, soul

Are any published monsters in Dungeons and Dragons 5th edition described as stealing souls (or otherwise interacting with souls)?

Answer (score 8):

From the Monster Manual:

- Demiliches are described as feeding souls to their phylacteries, but have no way to do so. Acererak-style demiliches devour souls.
- Night Hags trap souls in their Soul Bags.
- Liches feed souls to their phylacteries.

From Volo's Guide to Monsters:

- Barghests eat souls (along with the bodies they occupy).
- Devourers eat souls.
- Alhoons and Illithiliches (both varieties of mind flayer liches) feed souls to their phylacteries.